# How to check a string contains superscript or subscript in java

Tags: java, pdf, unicode

Is there a way to check if a string which is extracted from pdf document contains superscript or subscript

For example :

[image]

Comment: *"a string which is extracted from pdf document"* - how is that string extracted from the PDF? Does the string contain superscript/subscript or is that detail lost during extraction? The current answers to your question assume the former but your mentioning the origin of the string to me seems to point towards the latter.

Comment: i think the question is valid.. +1 mr john doe

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

One way is to get a list of all the Unicode characters required, and search your `String` for them programmatically.

For example, *km²* contains superscript, and the Unicode value is u00B2

So check your `String` along the lines of:

```
if(yourString.contains("\u00B2")){
            System.out.println("yay");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

***1 Pure Unicode***

The following would replace all Unicode characters not in script superscript/subscript with empty string, leaving only super/subscripts.

The problem is that there exists superscript and subscript that are not categorized there, like `²³`. See the wikipedia. These have to be listed.

```
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?U)[^²³\\p{InSuperscripts_and_Subscripts}]", ""));

boolean isSuperOrSubscript(int codePoint) {
    return Character.getName(codePoint).contains("SUPERSCRIPT")
        || Character.getName(codePoint).contains("SUBSCRIPT")
        || new String(new int[] {codePoint}, 0, 1)
                .matches("(?U)\\p{InSuperscripts_and_Subscripts}");
}
```

The above will however not find `ᵈ` for instance.

***2 PDF styled text***

PDF is a "type setting" of original styled text. As such superscripts could be smaller text moved a bit higher. The original `<sup>...</sup>` (to say) no longer available. Maybe recognizable by a human by its **font** resource in the PDF being for a smaller font.

In that case you might iterate through the text elements and look at the positioning. For instance with the **itext** library. No fun.